# How to calculate distance matrices for points based on common denominator?

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I am dealing with a vector layer containing ~3400 points. All of them have an individual identifying code (`Name`) and another one (`Network`) they share with others of the dataset since they belong a larger network. Thus the attribute table looks somewhat like this:

```
 Network  Name   AdditionalInformation
 a        Name1  Some
 a        Name2  Information
 a        Name3  Is
 a        Name4  Written
 b        Name5  In 
 b        Name6  This
 b        Name7  Field
```

What needs to be done is calculating the maximum distance between several points belonging to the same network (these are more than 500). However, my knowledge of calculation tools of this kind is limited to QGIS' Distance Matrix tool and I do not see a suitable solution for this entire dataset.

What might be the best way to proceed here?

Is there any way, for instance, to use the Python console in order to calculate distance matrices for each and every network based on the common denominator `Network` and save all maximum values to a CSV file afterwards?

---

I split the layer into smaller ones and saved them accordingly. The script, copied from Joseph, is now:

```
import glob, os, processing

path = "G:\ZIM\Analyse_Foerderprogramme\_ZIM-SOLO und ZIM-KOOP 2014\GIS\Adressen_TOMTOM\Split"
output_path = "G:\ZIM\Analyse_Foerderprogramme\_ZIM-SOLO und ZIM-KOOP 2014\GIS\Adressen_TOMTOM\Split\Ergebnisse"
field_1 = "NAME"
field_2 = "GEOCODE"

for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
    processing.runalg("qgis:distancematrix", layer, field_1, layer, field_2, 2, 0, output_path + os.path.basename(layer) + ".csv")
```

Yet nothing is happening so far after typing it into the console. I am but a beginner in the usage of the Python console so surely I made a mistake. What next?

---

The earlier mistake was the use of `\` instead of the proper `/`. Now, the script (with more readable paths) looks like:

```
import glob, os, processing

path = "H:/Split/"
output_path = "H:/Split/Ergebnisse/"
field_1 = "NAME"
field_2 = "GEOCODE"

for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
    processing.runalg("qgis:distancematrix", layer, field_1, layer, field_2, 2, 0, output_path + os.path.basename(layer) + ".csv")
```

This results in the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:/Split/Ergebnisse/Adressen_projiziert_Info_NAME__G533.shp.csv' See log for more details`

Why does Python look for a CSV file at the very beginning instead of calculating first and writing the results in a file of this sort second?

---

Joseph's script works. However, the error message remains the same for the file I'm trying to work with. Can anyone tell me what the log message might point to?

```
2016-09-23T16:22:45 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 89, in processAlgorithm
                self.writer = outputFile.getTableWriter([])
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\outputs.py", line 245, in getTableWriter
                return TableWriter(self.value, self.encoding, fields)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py", line 668, in __init__
                with open(self.fileName, 'wb') as csvFile:
            IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/klinge/GIS/Split/Ergebnisse/Ausgangsdaten_Vorhaben__ZKN060503.csv'

2016-09-23T16:22:45 1   There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

---

The error message did not occur on another (Linux) computer.

Comment: Looks like you need to escape your backslash by either inserting it twice before your desired directory or use `r` before your path. I.e. `path = "G:\ZIM\Analyse_Foerderprogramme\_ZIM-SOLO und ZIM-KOOP 2014\GIS\Adressen_TOMTOM\\Split"`; or `path = r'G:\ZIM\Analyse_Foerderprogramme\_ZIM-SOLO und ZIM-KOOP 2014\GIS\Adressen_TOMTOM\Split'`

Comment: The error was another one, the path now works. However, there is the next error message after running the script.

Comment: I've edited my post, the output name was incorrect. Although I'm not quite sure if that will sove the problem as it was still working for me...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. The error message remains the same.

Comment: Try moving the shapefiles and set the paths to your main `C:/` drive. I'm guessing the `H:/` drive is external?

Comment: Yes, it is. But apparently, this wasn't the problem. Instead of using the original shapefile, I created a new one after the example provided above. When applied to that very example, the script ran perfectly fine and produced two csv files. Therefore, I figure, there must be a flaw in my original shapefile (I'm trying to create it new right now). In the meantime, any advice on how to proceed from there? Eventually, if all goes as planned, I am going to end up with 500+ csv files. What could be a good way to i) merge them and ii) read out the maximum values for each network?

Comment: Always great when the original shapefile messes things up! In regards to your question, I would [combine your csv files to one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512386/how-to-merge-200-csv-files-in-python) by running the code in the **Python Console**. Then, if you're using Excel, open the merged csv and create a [Pivot Table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) to extract the maximum distance for each network. Or load the merged csv back into QGIS and use the **GroupStats** plugin which is essentially a pivot table for QGIS =)

Comment: That sounds doable. On another computer the error message did not occur; so hopefully things are going to run smoothly from here.

Comment: Let's hope so, let us know how you get on :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do the following:

1. Load your point layer into QGIS and run the **Split vector layer** with `Network` as the *Unique ID field*. The results will be saved to a directory.
2. Run the following code in the **Python Console**. It uses the same **Distance matrix** tool but only calculates the points for each `Network` and outputs the statistics including the *maximum distance*. Change the paths and field names accordingly:

   ```
   import glob, os, processing

   path = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/Folder/"
   output_path = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/Folder/Results/"
   field_1 = "Field_1"
   field_2 = "Field_2"

   for layer in glob.glob(path + "*.shp"):
       processing.runalg("qgis:distancematrix", layer, field_1, layer, field_2, 2, 0, output_path + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0] + ".csv")
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time; unfortunately, I am stuck at the next step (see edit).

Comment: @T.K. If you have another question then please ask it as a new question so that you can upvote and Accept Joseph's answer to this one.