# python queries distance the nearest object

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, distance, knn

I have 2 point layers, I want to calculate the shortest distance between 2 point layers by python code and enclose the conditions of satisfaction. 
For example, a point a when there is the shortest distance with point b and this a point must have  a field that satisfies the given condition.

Is there any python to do it?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html should be close with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis to ensure the from and to layers satisfy the attribute conditions. This can be scripted like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211659/how-to-calculate-distance-matrices-for-points-based-on-common-denominator